# Hash Map implementation with a function to set all values

Tags: java, performance, hash-map

This is an interview question I saw online and thought to give it a try.
The question is about implementing a hash map with a `setAll(V value)` function. This function assignes a value to all the keys in the map at `O(1)`.
Examples:

```
HashMapSetAll<Integer,String> map = new HashMapSetAll<Integer,String>();
map.put(1, "1");
map.put(2, "2");
map.setAll("all");
map.put(3,"3");

System.out.println(map.get(1)); // prints "all"
System.out.println(map.get(2)); // prints "all"
System.out.println(map.get(3)); // prints "3"
```

I added the implementation below - please tell me what you think about it - I mostly care about correctness and efficiency.

Also, pay attention to the call to `Thread.sleep(0,1)` - the reason I'm calling it is beacuase `isAfter` method of `ZonedDateTime` smallest unit compare is nano-seconds (and I want to make sure that at least one nano-seconds passes between to calls to `ZonedDateTime.now()`). Please tell me if there is a cleaner way of doing this time compare.

HashMapSetAll.java:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapSetAll<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

    private Map<K,ZonedDateTime> keyDates;
    private ZonedDateTime setAllTime;
    private V setAllVal;

    public HashMapSetAll() {
        super();
        keyDates = new HashMap<K,ZonedDateTime>();
        setAllTime = null;
        setAllVal = null;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        ZonedDateTime time = this.keyDates.get(key);
        if (time == null)
            return null;

        if ( (this.setAllTime == null) || (time.isAfter(this.setAllTime)) )
            return super.get(key);

        return this.setAllVal;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V oldVal = super.put(key, value);

        this.keyDates.put(key, ZonedDateTime.now());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(0, 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return oldVal;
    }

    public void setAll(V value) {
        this.setAllTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(0, 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setAllVal = value;
    }   
}
```

Also added some tests in HashMapSetAllTest.java:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class HashMapSetAllTest {

    HashMapSetAll<Integer, String> setAllMap = new HashMapSetAll<Integer, String>();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        setAllMap.clear();
    }

    @Test
    void testPutFirst() {
        String val = setAllMap.put(1, "hi");
        assertNull(val);

    }

    @Test
    void testPutSecond() {
        String val;

        setAllMap.put(1, "hi");
        val = setAllMap.put(1, "hi2");

        assertTrue(val.equals("hi"));   
    }

    @Test
    void testGetNormalNull() {
        assertNull(setAllMap.get(1));
    }

    @Test
    void testGetNormalValue() {
        setAllMap.put(1, "hi");
        assertTrue(setAllMap.get(1).equals("hi"));
    }

    @Test
    void testGetValAfterSetAll() { // value assigned after setAll
        setAllMap.setAll("all");
        setAllMap.put(1, "mine");

        assertTrue(setAllMap.get(1).equals("mine"));
    }

    @Test
    void testGetValBeforeSetAll() { // values assigned before setAll
        setAllMap.put(1, "mine");
        setAllMap.setAll("all");

        assertTrue(setAllMap.get(1).equals("all"));
    }

    @Test
    void testGetValBeforeAndAfterSetAll() { // values assigned before setAll
        setAllMap.put(1, "1");
        setAllMap.setAll("all");
        setAllMap.put(2, "2");

        assertTrue(setAllMap.get(1).equals("all"));
        assertTrue(setAllMap.get(2).equals("2"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution, replacing all values, is \$O(n)\$ - the trick is to do it in \$O(1)\$. With that in mind, your approach makes sense - store the new 'all' value, and customize `get` so it knows whether it should return the actual value for a key or the 'all' value.

I wouldn't use insertion time for that, however - that'll lead to hacks like `Thread.sleep`. A counter field that is only incremented when you call `setAll` should work just fine.

I would also wrap `V` in a custom class that stores both `V` and the last-modified-counter-value, so `get` doesn't need to perform two hash-map lookups in the worst case.

---

With that, `get` would look something like this:

```
public V get(K key) {
    VWrapper wrapper = super.get(key);
    if (wrapper.counter < setAllCounter)
        return setAllVal;
    return wrapper.value;
}
```

In your example, at the end keys 1 and 2 would have a counter value of 0 (they were added before any `setAll` call), 3 has a counter value of 1 (it was added after the first `setAll` call) and `setAllCounter` is 1 (`setAll` has been called one time).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Two things: first, how can I call the HashMap constructor for creating map with type <K, Wrapper>, when the generics for HashMapSetAll are <K,V>?                      
Second, I thought about the idea of counter field - but that can cause an overflow - how can you handle overflow case?

Comment: You can't if you inherit from `HashMap<K,V>`, but you can if you implement the `Map<K,V>` interface, while using an internal `HashMap<K,VWrapper>` for the actual work. During an interview I would only implement the most relevant methods though, and explain what else I would do if I had more time. Your approach is also ok, as long as you explain the trade-offs. As for overflow, an int will let you call `setAll` 2 billion times, a long allows 9 quintillion. Should be plenty for most use-cases.